# Why is JSON.Parse saying "invalid character"?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a piece of JS running in IE with the following line:

```js
var data = JSON.parse("{ skill: 'SK_AUTO_DEV_TEST', kind: 'IS_REQUIRED' }");
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: Please have a look at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). It's an online validator that gives pretty good error messages.

Answer (score 16):

Because that is not Valid JSON – you need quotes around the property names.

```
JSON.parse('{ "skill": "SK_AUTO_DEV_TEST", "kind": "IS_REQUIRED" }');
```

Comment: Thanks.  Why are quotes required around the property names?  I have seen that is not always the case w/ JSON parsers.

Comment: The standard requires the double quotes. `JSON.parse()` follows that and maybe the other parser you used was relaxed on that rule. The reason is to get around the reserved word issue. Make a simple object in a JavaScript file and try `{ if : 0 }` and `{ "if" : 0 }`. Guess which one is an error?

Comment: Hello @epascarello, any idea how to handle below piece of code 
`var text =  '{ "skill": "SK_AUTO_DEV_TEST", "kind": "IS_REQUIRED" }';
JSON.parse(text);` For me its saying Invalid Char at parse line. I tired in w3school with single quote, there its working but in my javascript its adding double quotes at the beginning and end thts make my parse statement like `JSON.parse("{ "skill": "SK_AUTO_DEV_TEST", "kind": "IS_REQUIRED" }");`

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on epascarello's answer, please refer to [json.org](http://json.org/). Note in the first diagram that the name in the name/value pair is defined as "string". Then note in the diagram that defines "string" that it must begin and end with double-quote. Also note that this applies to both name and value.